# Navigate to Ruby function definition in VS Code 2023

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code and ruby 2.3.1. I used to use Ruby by Peng Lv, and it worked well, but now it has been replaced with Ruby LSP. However, it's not working with ruby 2.3.1

How can I navigate from a function call to its definition in Ruby code now?

Comment: Why do you want to use a version of Ruby that was released more than 7 years ago, which reached end-of-life in 2019, and is unsupported for more than 4 years already?

Comment: @spickermann I am just maintaining an old project, and my customers don't want to upgrade it.

Comment: You should charge extra when you cannot use the new language features, performance improvements, and security fixes that were added to up-to-date versions since then.